# Create View Model based on Wizard with 3 steps / 3 Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have a Wizard with 3 steps / 3 Views, each View has it's own ViewModel, and I need to insert with one submit all the information from the 3 Views.

All the Views are included in a master View using the Html.RenderAction method.

```
@:<!--- Step1 --->
<div class="company-add-step5-elements-container">@{ Html.RenderAction(MVC.Company.CreateS1NameAddress()); }</div>

@:<!--- Step2 --->
<div class="company-add-step2-elements-container">@{ Html.RenderAction(MVC.Company.CreateS2Services()); }</div>

@:<!--- Step3 --->
<div class="company-add-step3-elements-container">@{ Html.RenderAction(MVC.Company.CreateS3Schedule()); }</div>
```

ViewModel for the Step1:

```
// Primary properties
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorMsgRequiredField", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(HeelpResources))]
public string CompanyName { get; set; }

public string Telephone { get; set; }
```

ViewModel for the Step2:

```
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(HeelpResources), Name = "AddressViewModelAddressLabel")]
public string Address1 { get; set; }

public string Address2 { get; set; }
```

ViewModel for the Step3:

```
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(HeelpResources), Name = "AddressViewModelCityLabel")]
public string City { get; set; }
```

Now how can I create a ViewModel to submit all the steps:

```
public class CompanyCreateViewModel
{
    // How can I merge everything here without repeating all the properties?
}
```

Thanks

Comment: sounds like a job for [automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/). That said, what's really wrong with having 5 property assignments?

Or are you asking how to store the 3 different view model states between steps?

Comment: Hi, the question is how to merge the 3 ViewModels to submit for Insertion. I get the information from 3 Views but I only want to submit one.